# Pyspark to read csv

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

New to pyspark and would like to read csv file to dataframe. cant seem to have it read. Any help?

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import Row
import csv


sql_c = SQLContext(sc)

rdd = sc.textFile('data.csv').map(lambda line: line.split(","))

rdd.count()
```

Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 rdd.count()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Spark 2, the preferred way is

```
df = sql_c.read.csv('data.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

To read csv independent of the spark version:

```
if sc.version.startswith("2"):
     csv_plugin = "csv"
else:
     csv_plugin = "com.databricks.spark.csv"

dataframe = sql_c.read.format(csv_plugin).options(header='true', inferSchema='true').load('data.csv')
```

Remove `header='true'` if you don't have a header.